# Deploying my site, lots of small script files. Long loading time

Tags: javascript, css, load

I've built a web application.
In my application I have many javascript and css files .
They are separated based on my application's logic.
I am talking about close to 20 of these files (each file is 2 kb +-).
They seem to take quite a while to download (6 - 10 seconds altogether).

What would you do to cut down the download time? Are there any best practices in this field?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join all JavaScript and all CSS files into one big JS and one big CSS file, and [minify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minification) them.

Answer (score 3):

You can compress your file by removing spaces, use short variable names, etc. Try looking for tools that are around for that purpose. Also, you can add all scripting to one file so that only one files needs to be downloaded and you can introduce some caching mechanism to prevent downloading the script over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

http://rakaz.nl/2006/12/make-your-pages-load-faster-by-combining-and-compressing-javascript-and-css-files.html
[http://driven-monkey.com/?p=97]
check these out